# Search a pattern in list of arrays and select a variable if pattern found in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to get a string from an array but am having some trouble with getting the required output. I tried using regex and if conditions but that's not very helpful
My array

```
com..JP.ap.adapter.AccountPayableCopybookAdapter#JP.AP.ADAPTER.REQUEST.componentLevel
com..JP.ap.adapter.AccountPayableCopybookAdapter#JP.AP.ADAPTER.REQUEST.queueName = JP.AP.ADAPTER.REQUEST
com..JP.ap.adapter.AccountPayableCopybookAdapter#JP.AP.ADAPTER.REQUEST.resetBrowseTimeout
com..JP.ap.adapter.AccountPayableCopybookAdapter#JP.AP.ADAPTER.REQUEST.securityProfileName
com..JP.ap.adapter.AccountPayableCopybookAdapter#JP.AP.ADAPTER.REQUEST.serializationToken
com..JP.ap.adapter.AccountPayableCopybookAdapter#JP.AP.ADAPTER.REQUEST.topicProperty
com..JP.ap.adapter.AccountPayableCopybookAdapter#JP.AP.ADAPTER.REQUEST.validateMaster
com..JP.ap.adapter.AccountPayableCopybookAdapter#JP.AP.SERVICE.REQUEST.queueManagerName
com..JP.ap.adapter.AccountPayableCopybookAdapter#JP.AP.SERVICE.REQUEST.queueName = JP.AP.SERVICE.REQUEST
com..JP.ap.adapter.AccountPayableCopybookAdapter#JP.AP.SERVICE.REQUEST.replyToQ
com..JP.ap.adapter.AccountPayableCopybookAdapter#JP.AP.SERVICE.REQUEST.replyToQMgr
com..JP.ap.adapter.AccountPayableCopybookAdapter#JP.AP.SERVICE.REQUEST.securityProfileName
com..JP.ap.adapter.AccountPayableCopybookAdapter#JP.AP.SERVICE.REQUEST.validateMaster
com..JP.ap.adapter.AccountPayableCopybookAdapter#TransformInvoice_COBOL_TO_XML.dataSource
com..JP.ap.adapter.AccountPayableCopybookAdapter#TransformInvoice_COBOL_TO_XML.validateMaster
com..JP.common.exceptionhandler.FireAndForget_FlatFile#BuildErrorNotification.dataSource
com..JP.common.exceptionhandler.FireAndForget_FlatFile#BuildErrorNotification.validateMaster
com..JP.common.exceptionhandler.FireAndForget_FlatFile#IsLastAttempt?.dataSource
com..JP.common.exceptionhandler.FireAndForget_FlatFile#JP.EXCEPTION.queueManagerName
com..JP.common.exceptionhandler.FireAndForget_FlatFile#JP.EXCEPTION.queueName = JP.EXCEPTION
com..JP.ap.AccountPayableService#providerPolicySetBindings
com..JP.ap.AccountPayableService#securityProfileName
com..JP.ap.AccountPayableService#monitoringProfile
com..JP.ap.AccountPayableACH#JP.AP.ACH.REQUEST.queueManagerName
com..JP.ap.AccountPayableACH#JP.AP.ACH.REQUEST.queueName = JP.AP.ACH.REQUEST
com..JP.ap.AccountPayableService#FireAndForget_SOAP.AlertEmailList = 
com..JP.ap.AccountPayableService#FireAndForget_SOAP.BackOutThreshold = 1
com..JP.ap.AccountPayableService#FireAndForget_SOAP.LogLevel = ERROR
com..JP.ap.AccountPayableService#FireAndForget_SOAP.MaxPerInterval = 0
com..JP.ap.AccountPayableService#FireAndForget_SOAP.NotificationInterval = 0
com..JP.ap.AccountPayableService#JP.AP.SERVICE.FAILURE.queueManagerName
com..JP.ap.AccountPayableService#JP.AP.SERVICE.FAILURE.queueName = JP.AP.SERVICE.FAILURE
```

Now i just need the strings after "queueName =" from the array and I want them uniq and sorted.

```
JP.AP.ACH.REQUEST
JP.AP.ADAPTER.REQUEST
JP.AP.SERVICE.FAILURE
JP.AP.SERVICE.REQUEST
JP.EXCEPTION
```

I tried:

```
foreach $_ (@array){
  if (/ .* queueName = '(.*?)'/){
    print ("$1\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the regex you tried.

Comment: I am using 

    foreach $_ (@array){
    if (/ .* queueName = '(.*?)'/){print ("$1\n");}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my %uniques;
my $string_pattern = "queueName = ";
foreach (@string_array)
{
        if($_ =~ m/$string_pattern/)
        {
                my ($junk, $pattern) = split($string_pattern, $_);
                $uniques{$pattern} = 1;
        }
}

foreach (sort keys %uniques)
{
        print $_."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) the array for `queueName =` to get the filtered array, then [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) those filtered results to a hash to get only the stuff at the end and toss duplicates, and then take the keys from the hash and [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) them.

This would look roughly like

```
my @rray = # ...however you get it
my %uniques = map {
  my $bite = MOREREGEX on $_;
  $bite => 1
} grep(SOMEREGEX,@rray);
return sort(keys %uniques)
```

EDIT: while I think using the `grep` makes it a bit clearer what the programmer intends (in my solution), it's possible to integrate what @Bruce answered to avoid using it

```
my @rray = # ...however you get it
my %uniques = map {
  my ($junk,$want) = split('queueName = ',$_);
  $want => 1
} @rray;
return sort(keys %uniques)
```

since when the split does not actually occur, `$want` is `''` <strike>and the `undef` key isn't pulled out by `keys`</strike>.

Error fix: actually the `''` key is in there, but it'll always be first after the sort, and can just be `shift`ed off.